# Debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 I have all torrents client use only 100 MB speed but I have worked 1 GB

Tags: debian, bittorrent

I have server in local network and i have problem with local speed.
On this server I put deluged 1.2.3 opentracker.
So when users download torrent for all peers availeble speed is 100 mb, but if in this time i opening ftp and start download I can use full 1 gb channel.
Why torrent clients can use all channel?

Comment: [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent) is a fairly complex protocol...[There are many possible issues limiting your speed. (Are you on cable?)](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentFAQ#Cable_usage:_Is_it_normal_to_get_upload_speeds_of_2-20_times_download_speed.3B_both_overall_and_per_peer.3F_I_can.27t_believe_that_total_download_speed_of_1-5_KB.2Fsec_is_normal.3B_I.27d_be_much_better_off_using_regular_FTP.21)  Not sure if they apply in a local setting, too, though.

Answer (score 1):

Bittorrent uses checksumming and multiple connections.  It will require quite a bit more CPU and cause much more disk seeking than FTP.  Check the output of `top`, `iostat`, `vmstat`, etc to see what is your limiting factor.

Comment: Thanks. Tommorow I'll try another computer. It be core2duo 3ghz 3gb memory. I want install on thic pc ubuntu 12.04 and create raid 0 on 4X3tb hards, for filesystem I'll choose xfs. I have around 2 tb files or 600 torrents. Also I put site on nginx+php, opentracker and deluge. On current machine I use same hardaware cpu load at 10-20% memory using 200-300 mb active uploads in deluge 15-25.